# How do I create a VS C# project for a lamda function to handle a Amazon IoT developer button event?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have looked all over the AWS documentation and googled for two days and cannot seem to find anything that says anything about this. It's easy as can be to create the function using C# in the AWS Lambda console but you can't manage the code in VS that way. There's walkthroughs, tutorials, and examples for many other kinds of things but apparently not for a C# project for an IoT developer button.

Comment: Lambs function can be invoked by various events such as SQS, SNS, Cloud Watch, S3. You can create a lambda which will triggered on SQS event and from IoT button click you put a message in SQS. That will invoke the lambda.

Comment: So, when working with the AWS project types in VS, you want to choose an SQS template. I mean it kind of looks right since it looks for SQSEvent.SQSMessage and ILambdaContext objects. Let me poke and prod and see what happens. Will update.

Comment: You had the correct answer. Please post that as an answer so I can accept it and add additional information for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda functions are designed to be triggered by some events and also they don't run infinitely.

The event source can be SQS, SNS, API Gateway, S3, CloudWatch or cron schedule.

For your use case, you can create a lambda which will triggered on SQS event and from IoT button click you put a message in SQS. That will invoke the lambda.

Comment: Correct. One of the things to note about the new default projects setup by the AWS project template is that the event passed in is ultimately cast into the parameter type specified in the method signature. That is to say that it's really just a json string and you can cast it into the correct type. If you cast it into the incorrect type, it won't really have the properties and values you expect but it won't error and will still find your function handler.